# How to auto-increment table-name during create-table, if table exists with same name

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm trying to auto-increment table-name while creating a new table.

Below one, is the generic way to do it.

`CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name column_type);`

How can we add an auto-increment to table name like: table_name1, table_name2, etc?

Comment: If you have to create this kind of incrementing table names, I would be concerned that it's a bad database design. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3833886/20860

Comment: Hi, @BillKarwin, thanks for the heads up! My use-case is quite different. It's kinda like creating a GUI for tables. So if a user creates new table, I have to create a table_name, if he goes with the default.

Comment: Why not require the user to name their tables? Tables should have distinct names that describe their content.

Comment: Yaa but if they don't wanna change it, they should be able to go with the default. It's the similar behavior you can see with the workbench.

Comment: That seems weird to me. When they create new files on their computer, are they all named "New file 1", "New file 2", etc.? How do they expect to find anything?

Comment: If I understood it correctly, I'm sure it does, at least on windows. Like if you create a txt file with the default name, it goes like: New Text Document.txt, New Text Document (2).txt, New Text Document (3).txt, etc.

Comment: That's true, and my point is that they should then _change_ the filenames to be more descriptive. Likewise, they should not create tables in a database without giving them better names than `table_name2`.

Comment: Sure, it makes sense. That's always a possibility to change names, this one is just for defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "auto incrementing" functionality with table names, you should handle it yourself. You can, for example, count the tables in your database with specific names and in specific schema:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'YOUR_SCHEMA' AND table_name LIKE '%YOUR_TABLE_NAME%';
```

Increase the number you got in result and create a new table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is there a way to get Max() of alphanumeric table-name like, if we have table_name1, table_name2 with ```SHOW TABLES FROM ${userSchema} WHERE Tables_in_${userSchema} LIKE '%table_name%'```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I got the idea from your update to deal with it & have added one more missing case to it. That is, if I delete a table from between the sequence then this might not work correctly. so I added ```SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(table_name),12) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '${userSchema}' AND table_name LIKE '%table_name%';```

Comment: @SahajRana I'm happy I helped! I thought you might have a problem with sequential numbers, but I tried to stick to answering the original question. Feel free to accept the answer if you think it solved your problem ;)

Comment: sure, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @errata, I have solved this problem. If I have tables with names: table_name1, table_name2, table_name_100, table_name_120.

I wanted to add an increment to a new table. So in the first part, I fetched the max count of the alpha-numeric table name.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(table_name),12) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '${userSchema}' AND table_name LIKE '%table_name%';
```

It returns, for example, `120` in the above case.

Use this and increment with 1 to new table_name.